# packrat on sub-directory only

Tags: r, packrat

I have an RStudio project which contains development code and production code.
I started this way before I know anything about packrat so I am only packrating it now.

However, I only want to packrat the production code, all sitting in a sub-directory inside the main project folder. How do I do that?

The `packrat::init` function seems only to run on the project level.

Comment: I'm not sure your question. `packrat` is a package dependency management system. It does not "store" code if that's what you're after.